# Thai drivers license in Costa Rica

Tags: car-rentals, driving-licenses, costa-rica, motorcycles, thai-citizens

I have a Thai Drivers license and Motorcycle license. Is this valid to rent a car / motorcycle in Costa Rica?

Answer (score 7):

Any foreign driver license is valid in Costa Rica for 3 months from the arrival date.
It is very important that you carry at the rental time the valid driver license and the passport as the rental agents are required to check and copy the arrival date stamp on your passport. I have 15 years working in the car rental industry in Costa Rica.

Answer (score 2):

Any valid international drivers license is allowed to rent a car, a couple of things, you must carry your passport with you at all times and the entry for Costa Rica must be less than 3 months, should you stay for longer than 3 months you are required to apply for a drivers license.